# Discord.py on_reaction_add

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have made super simple ticket system with reactions but it is not working :c. Here is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if 'React with  to create a ticket' in reaction.message.embeds and reaction.emoji == '':
        role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="@everyone")
        chan = await user.guild.create_text_channel(name=f'ticket - {user}')
        await chan.set_permissions(role, send_messages=False, read_messages=False, add_reactions=False, embed_links=False, attach_files=False, read_message_history=False, external_emojis=False)
        await chan.set_permissions(user, send_messages=True, read_messages=True, add_reactions=True, embed_links=True, attach_files=True, read_message_history=True, external_emojis=True)
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Ticket",
            description="React with  to close a ticket",
            color=0
        )
        embed.set_footer(text="Ticket system")
        msg = await chan.send(embed=embed)
        await msg.add_reaction("")

    if 'React with  to close a ticket' in reaction.message.content and reaction.emoji == '':
        await reaction.channel.delete()


@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def newticket(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel = None):
    if channel==None:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Ticket",
            description="React with  to create a ticket",
            color=0
        )
        embed.set_footer(text="Ticket system")
        msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await msg.add_reaction("")

    else:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Ticket",
            description="React with  to create a ticket",
            color=0
        )
        embed.set_footer(text="Ticket system")

        msg = await channel.send(embed=embed)
        await msg.add_reaction("")
```

I don't have any errors. But when I react to and embed message nothing happens so I think error is in this line: `if 'React with  to create a ticket' in reaction.message.embeds and reaction.emoji == '':` As you see I tried to make script that will create a channel if in embed content is 'React with  to create a ticket' (it in description) and if someone react with .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reaction.message.embeds` returns a list of embeds the message has. That means you cannot access the description content of an embed from this. You have to get the `discord.Embed` instance, then you can use `.description` attribute of `discord.Embed` class. It returns you the description content of the embed.

```py
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if 'React with  to create a ticket' in reaction.message.embeds[0].description and reaction.emoji == '' and not user.bot:
    ...
```

## References

- [`discord.Embed.description`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.description)
- [`discord.Message.embeds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.embeds)

Comment: Thanks, it works but when I type newticket bot create me ticket channel and and embed message and I wanted to create only embed message.

Comment: I edited the answer, it creates a channel because bot is also adding a reaction.

Comment: You also have to add  `and not user.bot` in the last if condition of `on_reaction_add` event.